# Bison Flex cannot access first token in bison rule section

Tags: parsing, bison, lex, flex-lexer

Flex:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
    #include "syntax.hpp"
    #include <cstdlib>
    extern "C" int isatty(int);
%}
%%

\#.*                                                {}
\[[A-Za-z_]*\]                                      {yylval.val_char=yytext; return SECTION_NAME;}
[A-Z_a-z[:digit:]]*[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z[:digit:]]*     {yylval.val_char=yytext ;return OPTION_NAME;}
\n                                                  {}
=\".*?\"                                            {yylval.val_char=yytext+1; return VALUE_STRING;}
=[ A-Z_a-z[:digit:]]*[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z[:digit:] ]*  {yylval.val_char=yytext+1; return VALUE_ENUM;}
=[ [:digit:] ]*                                     {yylval.val_int=atoi(yytext+1); return VALUE_INTEGER;}
=[ [:digit:]\.[:digit:]]+                           {yylval.val_float=atof(yytext+1); return VALUE_FLOAT;}


" "                                                 {}
%%
```

Bison:

```
%{
    #include <iostream> 
    int yylex();
    int yyerror(const char *p) {return 0;}

%}

     %union  {
            float val_float;
            int val_int;
            char* val_char;
           };   
     %token <val_char> SECTION_NAME
     %token <val_char> OPTION_NAME
     %token <val_int> VALUE_INTEGER
     %token <val_float> VALUE_FLOAT
     %token <val_char> VALUE_STRING
     %token <val_char> VALUE_ENUM

%%
    input
        :input line
        |line
        ;
    line
       :section
       |value
       ;


    section
        :SECTION_NAME {std::cout<<$1; std::cout<<std::endl;}
        ;

    value
        :OPTION_NAME VALUE_INTEGER  {std::cout<<$1, std::cout<<std::endl;}
        |OPTION_NAME VALUE_FLOAT {std::cout<<$1; std::cout<<std::endl;}
        |OPTION_NAME VALUE_ENUM {std::cout<<$1; std::cout<<std::endl;}
        |OPTION_NAME VALUE_STRING {std::cout<<$1;std::cout<<std::endl;}
        ;
%%
```

I am trying to test small ini configuration file parser. It must parse option=value pairs, where value can be int,float,quoted string or enumaerated constant. This code should give SECTION_NAMEs and OPTION_NAMEs frome file to console output. But it does not. Instead of that it prints whole file. If I change $1 to $2 it works fine and prints SECTION_NAMEs and VALUES. What's wrong with it?  How can i get access to OPTION_NAME token value? Thanks in advance.

UPD. Flex part works fine. {printf(yylval.val_char); return OPTION_NAME;} gives right token value to console. Perhaps problem in bison part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning pointers into `yytext` for your token semantic values.  `yytext` is the internal buffer flex uses to match tokens, and its only valid until the next call to `yylex` to read the next token.  So your semantic values (`$1` etc) all end up being dangling pointers into a buffer that's being overwritten with more token data from later tokens.

You need to copy the string out of `yytext` to some storage that will be available longer.  `strdup` is very useful for this:

```
\[[A-Za-z_]*\]                                      {yylval.val_char=strdup(yytext); return SECTION_NAME;}
[A-Z_a-z[:digit:]]*[A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z[:digit:]]*     {yylval.val_char=stdrup(yytext); return OPTION_NAME;}
```

etc